# Can't use FBSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm writing login via Facebook in Swift app. I downloaded FacebookSDK, linked libs and created bridge header and added it to Objective-C bridging headers. Imported libraries in it:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

I tried to use classes, but have errors.

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
FBLoginView.self
```

Error: "use of unresolved identifier 'FBLoginView'"

Help me plz(

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:
 "import FBSDKCoreKit"
 "import FBSDKLoginKit"
 "import FBSDKShareKit"
 at the top of your AppDelegate.swift

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example project using Facebook Login](https://github.com/iDevelopMSD/FBMessengerShareLocation.git)